# Actionscript 3 - Add Mouse listener inside Mouse listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm having this problem : 
I want everytime i click for ex. picA, after i click picB sth like this

```
trace("Clicked picB after A");
```

Note:Clicking picB without clicking first picA, or clicking somewhere else like picC, and then picB wouldn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add listeners to all pics you wanted inside same function onClick. like this

```
  picA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
  picB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
  picC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
  picD.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
```

take a boolean variable which define if picA is clicked recently

```
  var isAClicked:Boolean = false;

 function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
switch (e.currentTarget.name)
{
    case 'picA' :
        isAClicked = true;
        break;
    case 'picB' :
        if (isAClicked)
        {
            trace("Clicked picB after A");
        }
        else
        {
            isAClicked = false;
        }
        break;
    default :
        isAClicked = false;
        break;
   }
}
```

In this if picA is clicked then you set the boolean value to true and if the picB is clicked next then you check if recently picA is clicked or not. If yes then you do whatever you want else set the boolean value to false. If anyother pic is clicked then you simply set boolean value to false just like i did in default case.

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: So, what if you have hundreds of objects? Your switch statement will grow proportionally.. Not the best solution

Comment: switch will never grow because all other cases will be handled by default case...

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onStageClick)


private function onStageClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    // to have only one PicB listener use removeEventListener before adding
    picB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPicBClick) 
    if(e.target === picA){
        picB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPicBClick)
    }
}

private function onPicBClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    picB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPicBClick)
    trace("Clicked picB after A");
}
```